# Visual Studio 2019 debugger blocks on Console.ReadLine when there is no console

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have a WinForms VB.NET app (.NET Framework 4.7.2) which starts up in Sub Main before showing the main form (Enable application framework is unchecked).

The app can be launched stand-alone, or from another app which redirects stdin to pass the app some info.

Therefore the child app has a call to Console.ReadLine() to check for info being passed from a parent process. If there is no parent process, ReadLine should immediately return null (Nothing) and we go on our way. This is how it behaves outside the debugger (i.e. just running the debug-build exe), and under the debugger on other machines and if I compile and debug with Rider (JetBrains IDE).

However on my machine, under the debugger in VS2019, it blocks on the Console.ReadLine() call as if it's waiting for input.

This is reproducible in a new application:

```vb
Public Module Program

    Public Sub Main()
        Console.ReadLine()
        Application.Run(Form1)
    End Sub

End Module
```

The same occurs (in VS but not Rider) in a new vanilla C# application, generated from the WinForms template with just the Console.ReadLine(); line added. The code has been in our VB app for years and nobody else on the team has the issue but I've repro'd it on my laptop and my own PC. Perhaps I have other libraries installed but I don't know where to start looking to explain this behaviour.

Any ideas anyone?

UPDATE:

Here's the stack trace as request by Hans. To clarify, the process is not hung, but waiting for input.

```
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.__ConsoleStream.ReadFileNative(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle hFile, byte[] bytes, int offset, int count, bool useFileAPIs, bool isPipe, out int bytesRead)
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.__ConsoleStream.Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.TextReader.SyncTextReader.ReadLine()
mscorlib.dll!System.Console.ReadLine()
ConsoleProbCS.exe!ConsoleProbCS.Program.Main()
```

Comment: @HansPassant It's not hung as such, just waiting for input. Stack trace added per your suggestion.

Comment: The callstack look weird, by default Console.ReadLine should call NullStreamReader.ReadLine in a WinForms app. In your example it seems stdin in redirected to a file. I would check if you accidently have "<some_file" in your project debug arguments, or you have some app installed that takes over stdin

Comment: Debug arguments are blank and I have no funky apps that would cause the issue (AFAIK). Found that the problem goes away if I turn on “Use Managed Compatibility Mode” in debugging options. Not ideal if it degrades other aspects of debugging.

Comment: Reported to Microsoft (will add issue number when I get one).